# ggplot2 add reference line with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet-wrap

I have the following code to produce a side by side scatter plots:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = xvar,y = yvar)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(grpvar)
```

I would like to add reference line y=x to those paneled plots, but only go the error message with the following added code:

```
+ abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

Any advice how to do this with multiple plots in a panel? Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if it's clear what you're asking. For code debugging please always ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description, with the desired output.

Comment: Try `+ geom_abline(yintercept=0, slope=1)` instead `+ abline(...`. If you provide a reproducible example would be easier to help...

Comment: Thanks Bruno! The geom_abline code worked!

Comment: To suggestions, I can't due to data sensitivity but will keep that in mind for future posting...

Comment: Even if there are security or other issues with your exact data, you can always make up or find dummy data that recreates the issue

Comment: You don't need to post a sample of your data, just some dummy data that have the same structure.

Comment: Great @Dwdata2b! I will put as an answer, but take in account what guys said above concerning dummy data for reproducible examples. It's always a need

Comment: Thanks all! I am not used to ask/answer coding questions, it'd take some practice for sure... :).

Answer (score 0):

In `ggplot2` geometric objects (points, lines, areas...) are inserted with a `geom_` prefix.

In your case you need to use

```
+ geom_abline(yintercept=0, slope=1)
```

instead of

```
+ abline(...)
```

So your code should be

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = xvar,y = yvar)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(yintercept=0, slope=1) +
  facet_wrap(grpvar)
```